# Android: generating a new SessionID every time an Activity is completed?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am creating an android application that contains 3 games, all in seperate activities. After each game the details of the session are written to an SQlite database (e.g. score etc).

I want to include a functionality that generates a sessionID for each game and is consistent and updated throughout all Activities. I.e. not a seperate ID for each.

For example:

```
Game 1 session completed: SessionID=1
Game 2 session completed: SessionID=2
another Game 2 session completed: SessionID=3
Game 3 session completed: SessionID=4 etc...
```

How can I do so?

In the meantime I am just using a generated random number(x) for SessionID that also isnt consistent throughout all activities:

```
//getting random number for sessionid (WILL BE CHANGED EVENTUALLY)
            Random ran = new Random();
            int x = ran.nextInt(1) + 3000;


            //Adding the new Score to the database. NOTE: SESSIONID NEEDS TO BE SORTED AND CHANGED TO PRIM KEY EVENTUALLY
            db.addScore(new Score(x, "Multiplication", UserName.getUserName(), averageMedLevel,medMax, 
                    averageAttLevel,attMax, score,myDate));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation here](http://sqlite.org/autoinc.html), you can specify a column in the database with the type `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`, which will ensure that;

```
The ROWID chosen for the new row is at least one larger than the largest ROWID that has
ever before existed in that same table. If the table has never before contained any data,
then a ROWID of 1 is used.
```

This would save you having to keep control of your sessionIds and let them be dictated by the ROWID of the database.

If you do want to track your own SessionIds, you can insert them as part of your insert statement using the following syntax;

```
INSERT INTO test1(rowid, a, b) VALUES(123, 5, 'hello');
```

For uniqueness and sorting when rolling your own, consider using a timestamp as the leading part of the SessionId (e.g. "yyyyMMddHHmmss + game id").

Comment: Thank you i used your suggestion of: (e.g. "yyyyMMddHHmmss + game id"). and it worked well for a primary key